# create textbox in php

Tags: php, image-processing

Is there any way to create a textbox of predefined width and height in php memory and store the text in it with word-wrapping, then return it line by line and store in array of variable.

I am actually trying to implement something similar to imagettfbbox but instead of returning dimensions, I want to return text in it line by line; so I could know that on which line and what place particular text or sentence would be after transforming into image.

Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You might use chunk_split() to wrap a long string and then 'explode' the string to an array, like this:

```
$mylongstring = 'a very long text etc';

// Place a 'newline' character every 50 characters
$mylongwrappedstring = chunk_split($mylongstring, 50);

// Split the lines to an array
$lineArray = explode("\n", $mylongwrappedstring);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

I'll leave the image-processing/generation to you :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this will not work for RTL languages like arabic or some other non-english languages.

Comment: Also we are interested in wrapping at pixel not at characters length.

Comment: I suggest to enhance you question offer more information as you didn't mention RTL languages as a requirement.

Comment: In order to determine what words will 'fit' in the amount of pixels, you'll probably have to append 1 character at a time, and use imagettfbbox() to check the dimensions, until the text no longer fits inside the desired width (in pixels)